# Few short questions on notational choice

Tags: notation, ordinals

There are few questions on notational choice that seem to come up a number of times. It seems that, while some of this might be somewhat context dependent, it might be useful to get a general idea. I will just briefly go through each of them.

**(Q1)** Suppose we wanted to identify an ordinal by taking some kind of minimum. We would sometime get two choices: **(1a)** $\min\{x \in \mathrm{Ord}\,|\,\,\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} x\}$. However, it could also be the case that we could (relatively easily) identify an ordinal $\alpha$ such that the above ordinal could equivalently be written as **(1b)** $\min\{x \in \alpha\,|\,\,\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} x\}$.

My feeling is that both are basically equally good and which is better is largely context dependent?

**(Q2)** Suppose we want to write a condition like ($a,b,c,d$ are specific ordinals): **(2a)**$\forall i \in \mathrm{Ord} \, \forall j \in \mathrm{Ord} \,[((a\leq i<b)\wedge (c\leq j<d))\rightarrow (\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} i,j) ]$.

Now suppose we are dealing with a scenario concerning only ordinals.It seems better to me to just write before-hand that the quantifications are meant to be over ordinals. But in that case, we still seem to get two choices: **(2b)** $\forall i  \, \forall j  \,[((a\leq i<b)\wedge (c\leq j<d))\rightarrow (\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} i,j) ] \,\,$  **(2c)** $\forall \, a\leq i<b  \, \forall \, c\leq j <d  \,[(\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} i,j) ] \,\,$.

Normally I would think that (2c) is better because it gets right to the main condition we are trying to express. But nevertheless, I am not sure. Another thing (that I initially ignored) seems to be that if we have a different combination of quantifier, it may be difficult to write our desired statement in the form (2a) or (2b).

**EDIT:** Something else occurred to me. Perhaps the best way may be to express it something like: **(2d)** $\forall \, i \in [a,b)  \, \forall \, j \in [c,d)  \,[(\mathrm{some\,condition\,involving\,} i,j) ] \,\,$.

I haven't seen interval notation like $[a,b)$ being used for ordinals before. Is it common place enough that one can use it freely without adding any description? **END**

**(Q3)** Suppose we have some (not in 'strict' set-theoretic sense) function $f:\mathrm{Ord} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ord}$ (suppose it is strictly increasing). Now it might happen that we are only interested in ordinals which belong to $range(f)$. But often we will not be using an explicit symbol for $f$ and we have (suppose) something like $\beta_i=f(i)$ for all ordinals $i$. So there seem to be two choices in referring to a relevant ordinal in that case.

We can say: Consider an ordinal $x$ such that $x=\beta_i$ for some $i\in \mathrm{Ord}$. The other option seem to be to define $X=\{\, \beta_i \,|\,i\in \mathrm{Ord}\}$. One could give such a definition in the beginning. Then later on, one can simply write $x \in X$. However, we will need to be consistent with the use of symbol $X$.

Now suppose we have some ordinal $\lambda \in X$ (using notation from 3b). If we have $\lambda=\beta_n$ and we need to refer ordinal $\beta_{n+\omega}$ again there seem to be two choices:

**(3a)** We just explicitly write $\lambda=\beta_n$ as above and then refer to $\beta_{n+\omega}$.

**(3b)** We "invent" a notation such $\alpha^{+x}$ ($x$ an ordinal). For example, if $\alpha \notin X$ then $\alpha^{+1}=\alpha^+$ could refer to smallest ordinal that is both greater than $\alpha$ and also belongs to $X$. So, in that case, we could just write $\lambda^{+\omega}$ for our required ordinal.

My feeling is that (3b) is a reasonable notation. But, I haven't seen a notation like $\alpha^{+x}$ (with ordinal $x$)  being used. Would it considered to be a reasonable notation or whether it might be better to avoid such short-hand in favour of (3a)?

---

Perhaps the answer to some of the questions are subjective enough (maybe especially Q3) that it might be hard to give a clear-cut answer? But probably, some perspective on (Q1),(Q2) might be beneficial.

Comment: The problem in (1) and (2) is that $\text{Ord}$ is a proper class, not a set. So any time you use it, you are involving a theory of classes, which means that you have to keep track which properties of ordinals only hold for sets, and which also hold for proper classes. If you are working in a context where you don't want to get into that, you need to stick with notations that don't mention "$\text{Ord}$. However, this does include using a boolean condition "$\text{ord}(\alpha)$" which is true when $\alpha$ is an ordinal. Or simply stating "is an ordinal".

Comment: **(1b)** only works with Von Neumann's definition of ordinals. There are other definitions, such in Conway's Surreals. **(2c)** is an informal notation, and if you are going that far, you might as well go the tiny bit further of actually using words to explain it rather than a pretended formalism. On (Q3), it is exceptable to define a notation when one is useful, as long as it is clearly explained, and isn't confusable with other common notations used in the same circumstances. However, I think **(3a)** is more comprehensible than **(3b)**.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply. Yes, I am assuming von neumann definition (since I that's the only one I learned and know how to use). For **(Q1)** and **(Q2)**, yes I am talking about a scencario where notation such as $f:\mathrm{Ord} \rightarrow \mathrm{Ord}$ or $range(f)$ has to be used. As an example of **(Q1)**, consider the following two definitions of $\omega$, $\min \{x \in \omega^2\,|\,\mathrm{x \, is  \, limit \, ordinal }\}$. But we might also write: $\min \{x \in \mathrm{Ord}\,|\,\mathrm{x \, is  \, limit \, ordinal }\}$. Now this is a rather contrived example. *[continue]*

Comment: However, it might often happen that the "upper-limit"  ordinal (such as $\omega^2$ in above case) might not be as obvious at all (even though it exists). And secondly, even if one can write such an "upper-limit" (without too much difficulty) explicitly, it might not be instructive to write it directly in a definition since it might not give any motivation for the actual definition. I am thinking about a scenario like that. For **(2c)**, I agree. However, if we have have to give such definitions repeatedly, I feel it would be better to use more symbols (than sentences every time). *[continue]*

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Also, a brief question. If we have ordinals $p,q$, we could define something like $[p,q]$ as $[p,q]=\{x \in max(p,q)+1 \,|\, p \leq x \leq q\}$. And similarly for other intervals. As I understand, a definition such as one for $[p,q]$ need not be written when $p,q$ are ordinals. Because I guess such a definition would be assumed (without have to write a definition everytime)? Is this right or is it better to write such a definition of "interval" when one has to use it?

Comment: Any notation has to be defined. However, if you can reasonably expect your audience to already be familiar with it, then it generally isn't needful, or even helpful, to repeat the definition yourself. Think about how tedious it would be if every math book developed the number system, base 10 notation, and the concepts of counting and arithmetric in detail before diving into the topic at hand. Intervals are definable on any linearly ordered set. If your audience has some experience with such sets other than the reals, you don't need to introduce intervals yourself.

Comment: @PaulSinclair "Intervals are definable on any linearly ordered set." That's a nice way to think about intervals. I hadn't about it before like that. Anyway, I understand what you are saying. Thanks for the input on this question. I will take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You've raised some interesting points about notation in set theory and ordinals. Here are my thoughts:

(Q1) Both notations, (1a) and (1b), are correct and the choice between them is largely context-dependent. If $\alpha$ is easily identifiable and makes the condition simpler or more intuitive, then (1b) might be preferred. Otherwise, (1a) is a more general notation that doesn't assume the existence of such an $\alpha$.

(Q2) Again, all notations (2a), (2b), and (2c) are correct. The choice depends on the context and personal preference. Notation (2c) is indeed more concise, but it might be less familiar to some readers. The interval notation (2d) is not commonly used for ordinals, but it's understandable if you explain it beforehand.

(Q3) The choice between (3a) and (3b) depends on the specific context and the audience's familiarity with the notation. If the notation $\alpha + x$ is clearly defined and does not conflict with other notations, it can be used. However, it's important to note that this notation is not standard, so it should be defined clearly when first used.

In general, the choice of notation can depend on many factors, including the specific mathematical context, the intended audience, and personal preference. It's always important to make sure that the notation you use is clear and well-defined to avoid any confusion.

I hope this helps! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.